# Ignore if specific character matched

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have a string:

```
$str = "yellow;yellow\;er;yellowest";
```

And I use preg_split like this:

```
preg_split("/;/", $str);
```

But I want to get results like this:

```
array(
    "yellow",
    "yellow;er",
    "yellowest"
)
```

But the results is not right.

So actually what I want to do is to split the string at a `;` but if the `;` has a `\` before it, it has to stay just `;`, remove the `\` and not split it there. So it has to split at `;` but not `\;` and if there is a `\;` it has to remove the `\` character. Something like with strings:

```
echo "Hello There \"Jacques\"";
```

Gives:

> Hello There "Jacques"

And not just:

> Hello There

Comment: You can't do it at the same time. Use Explosion Pills answer, and after use array_map with strtr to replace `\;` with `;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind to make sure that `;` is not preceded by a `\`

```
preg_split('/(?<!\\\);/', $str)
```